# Есть ли разница между макросами на экселе 2007 и 2019 года ? Заработают ли макросы сделанные на эксель 2019 в эксель 2007?

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Начал недавно изучать макросы и возник такой вопрос, ибо программированием никогда не занимался, но поставил такую себе задачу, чтобы изучить макросы и возник такой вопрос.

Comment: *Есть ли разница между макросами на экселе 2007 и 2019 года ?* Да. *Заработают ли макросы сделанные на эксель 2019 в эксель 2007?* 50/50.

Comment: Сам VBA  не изменился. Но если использовать новые инструменты, функции, которые появились в новых версиях, то, естественно, - как может работать то, чего нет?...

Comment: ВБА такой же но ВБА как язык макросов использует объекты и функции текущей версии Эксель. Разница только в этом и для 99% процентов проектов она не существенна